# SDL Core, could not be installed, No appender could be found for logger (SDLMain). log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly

Tags: ubuntu, log4cxx, smartdevicelink

I am new to Smartdevicelink framework, I am trying to connect my android app through tcp, in which while I am trying to install SDL Core in my local system, I come across below error...

```
log4cxx: Could not instantiate class [SafeFileAppender].
log4cxx: Class not found: SafeFileAppender
log4cxx: Could not instantiate appender named "SmartDeviceLinkCoreLogFile".
log4cxx: Could not instantiate class [SafeFileAppender].
log4cxx: Class not found: SafeFileAppender
log4cxx: Could not instantiate appender named "ProtocolFordHandlingLogFile".
log4cxx: Could not instantiate class [SafeFileAppender].
log4cxx: Class not found: SafeFileAppender
log4cxx: Could not instantiate appender named "ProtocolFordHandlingLogFile".
log4cxx: Could not instantiate class [SafeFileAppender].
log4cxx: Class not found: SafeFileAppender
log4cxx: Could not instantiate appender named "ProtocolFordHandlingLogFile".
log4cxx: Could not instantiate class [SafeFileAppender].
log4cxx: Class not found: SafeFileAppender
log4cxx: Could not instantiate appender named "ProtocolFordHandlingLogFile".
log4cxx: Could not instantiate class [SafeFileAppender].
log4cxx: Class not found: SafeFileAppender
log4cxx: Could not instantiate appender named "TransportManagerLogFile".
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (SDLMain).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to avoid all of these issues, I would recommend using the [Manticore web app](https://smartdevicelink.com/resources/manticore/), which allows you to use SDL Core through your web browser.

Otherwise, it would appear that your error is related to `log4cxx` not being installed properly on your system. You can see the [known dependency issues](https://github.com/smartdevicelink/sdl_core#known-dependency-issues) section of the SDL Core README for more details. The gist is that you may have to remove an existing log4cxx on your system before attempting to `cmake` your SDL Core.

Comment: I couldn't able to connect my device by using manticore web app, do I need to run sdlcore separate

Comment: The only reason you wouldn't be able to connect is if your wi-fi network is preventing it. You can also run SDL Core separately, but it's more difficult to configure properly than just opening a web page.